# Changing one antenna of my double-antenna router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, antenna

Recently I installed some ip cameras. One of them is laggy due to poor wifi reception. I'm currently using a [wifi-repeater](https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/products/dap-1360-wireless-n-open-source-access-point-router) to boost my wifi but still, is not enough (according to linssid i'm getting on average a -76 signal under the ip cam). The repeater comes with 2 antennas, 2dbi each. Can I change one of the two antennas with a higher gain one ([like this](https://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-5691_TL-ANT2408CL.html)) ? Is it dangerous for the repeater to have two different antennas, the 2dbi and the 8dbi, mounted at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) By exchanging the antenna, you may exceed the legal maximum transmission power in your country (an additional 6 dBi = four times the wattage). Fines and chances of getting caught depend on your country.

2) Your repeater/router uses the signal received on *both* antennas to decode the WLAN signal (details depend on the router and protocol). If you asymmetrically boost one antenna, reception may actually get worse, not better.

It's not like the repeater uses one antenna for the camera, and one antenna for the main router.

So if you want to use antennas with a higher gain, replace both antennas.

3) In principle, using an antenna with a higher gain is not dangerous.

4) Besides signal strength, there are a lot of other factors that influence reception. One very important one is the presence of other Wifi senders on the same channel (note that depending on the protocol, multiple channels are used). In addition, there's the [hidden station problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_node_problem), which becomes worse with increased range, and use of repeaters.

5) Your repeater will have first to receive the data, and then send it again on the same channel, halving available bandwidth.

6) So if you can, the best solution is to use LAN. Either attach the IP camera directly to LAN, or place an access point using a different non-overlapping channel range close to the IP camera (e.g., if the camera is outside), and connect it up via LAN to your main router.